# Why does my code not submit password and instead submits "login"

Tags: php, html, sqlite

When using Post I do not receive a password from my form I do however receive a message from my button.

Array ( [Username] => 000001 [login_btn] => Login )

Below is the code.

```
<form action="checklogin.php" method="post">
    <div class="wrap"> <!--make a container that will have all our elements and will be the main stucture of you pages-->
        <div class="logo"></div><!--The logo container-->
        <div class="header_text">Room Booking</div><!--The main header of the fomr-->
        <div class="logins_details_container"><!--The top container-->
            <table class="fields_container"> <!--A simple 2x2 table for the form. We choose to use table as for this simple kind of stuff helps us to be everything well stuctured and putting less attributes at the css-->
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Username</span></td>
                    <td><input class="field" id="Username" name="Username" value="" placeholder="" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Password</span></td>
                    <td><input class="field" id="Password" name="Password" value="" placeholder="" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="remeber_me_container"><!--A container for the Remember me text and the checkbox-->
                <div class="remember_me">Remember Me?</div>
                <input  id="remeber_me" name="" value="" type="checkbox" />
            </div>
            <div class="login_btn"><!-- The login button-->
                <input name="login_btn" value="Login" type="submit" />
            </div> 
        </div>
<form/><!-- End of the logins_details_container -->
```

Comment: Because your form doesn't have a submit button.

Comment: is the <div class="login_btn"><!-- The login button-->
                <input name="login_btn" value="Login" type="submit" />
            </div>  not a button? If not how would I change this?

Comment: Simple. Change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`.

Comment: @AmalMurali Ah gotcha cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<input name="login_btn" value="Login" type="button" />
```

to

```
<input name="login_btn" value="Login" type="submit" />
```

Comment: What if I want the button to say Login? Although I've been told that its ok the way it is?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will prevent the password being sent to your PHP script, but your above HTML page has a missing closing-div.

```
       <form action="checklogin.php" method="post">
             <div class="wrap">
                  <form/>
```

(i've removed all the other matching lines & the above 3 lines are remaining.)

You need to use  to close your form. but you have an extra DIV that is not closed.

I don't think it will affect the PHP - but just advising.   It will help if we see part of your PHP code too.

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML code looks OK. but you have not provided any of the PHP code.

some things that I find (when i get this error) are

- is your "Password" variable being  obtained in the php script ?
- Is the capitalisation of the Password correct (Password & not password).

can you echo / print the $password variable at the very start of the php script - after its retrieved/assigned to a variable ?

Comment: I used the print_r($_POST); to show everything that moves from one for to another and password just isnt going with it.